# Implementing a timer like that of Stackoverflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, timeout

Stackoverflow prevents one from posting too many comments in a short period of time, by granting him 15 seconds delay after posting each comment. In my Rails application, I want to implement a different feature that uses the same logic. If a user is reading a post for more than 5 minutes, I want to add him to the post's `readers` table. Is this done by using `sessions` or `cookies`?

Update: as I think about it more, the logic maybe slightly different. After 5 minutes, I need to check one more time if the user is still on the page, reading the post.

**Clarification:** I want to implement a method to check whether a user has been reading the same post for longer than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many questions you are asking, without knowing the workflow of your app its difficult to answer the question. Break it down so its much easier for others also.

Now, to answer part of your question, you can do the timing with session. Something like this maybe?

```
def methodName
  if session[:logged_in]
    do_something if session[:last_seen] < 5.minutes.from_now
    session[:last_seen] = Time.now
  else
    do_something_else
    session[:last_seen] = Time.now
  end
end
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.